# run function onclose phonegap childbrowser?

Tags: cordova, childbrowser

When Im opening a page in the childbrowser on page1 I want to run a function when I close it, and it works.
But when I go to page2 and open another page in the childbrowser it runs the function here as well and I dont want that.

So how can I run a function when I close the childbrowser on just page1 and not on page2?

Im using this on page1 to run the function when Im closing the CB.

```
   var apptypen='iPhone';

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (apptypen=='iPhone'){
        alert("apptype iphone");

    window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose=function(){

    jQT.goBack(1);
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = null;
        }
    }
    });
```

When I opens the CB on page1 it runs the alert and it goes back with the jQT.goBack(1); function, but if I open the CB on page2 it doesent run the alert, but it does run the jQT.goBack, and thats what I dont want. It should only run jQT.goBack when I open the CB on page1 and not when I open a page in the CB on page2.
Any input appreciated, thanks.
Solved, I had to have window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = null; after the jQT.goBack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to register a location change listener. Then when you move to page 2 you can set a global variable or remove the close listener. Your choice.

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(loc) {
    if (loc == "page1.html") {
        window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = function() {
           alert("close");
        };
    } else if (loc == "page2.html") {
        window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Simon, long time. Ok, but if I want to not run a function on any other pages that uses the CB, what would that look like?
else if(loc == "*")
or something?
Thanks.

Comment: else if (loc != "page1.html") for instance.

Comment: locationchange is the location in the CB, right?
So if the location in the CB changes then run a function?
If so, then I need to clarify, I don't want it to change depending on the page that Im opening IN the CB, I want it to run a function if I open the CB ON page1 and not if I open the CB ON page2.
:-)

Comment: Then all you need to do is to remove your onClose handler before you open page2.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I understand how it works :-) All I had to do was to set window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = null; after jQT.goBack(1);
Thanks a lot Simon.